# When given the index of coordinates to a multidimensional array, how can you calculate those coordinates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Conversely, I have a function that gives you the index of inputted coordinates.

```
function generateBoard(rows, cols, initialValue) {
let arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < rows;i++){
    arr.push(new Array(cols).fill(initialValue))
}
return arr;
}
```

If given:

```
const board = generateBoard(3,3," ");
```

It should produce an array as such, ["","",""],["","",""],["","",""], with for example coordinates 2,1 should print out 7.

How can we write:

```
function indexToRowCol(board, i){}
```

If a sample input of indexToRowCol(board, 8) should give you the coordinates of rows = x and cols = x? I am not sure how to calculate the values of rows and cols simply by the index parameter.

Comment: Why would `coordinates 2,1 print out 7.` When you initialize it to " ".

Comment: @just_a_simple_guy because if read in one line, 2,1 is the 7th element in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for row number divide i by board[0].length since that is number of elements you have to distribute in each row and take floor of that value, for column you have to find the leftover elements in last row, so

`row = parseInt(i/board[0].length)` and `column = i - row*board[0].length -1`

```js
function generateBoard(rows, cols, initialValue) {
let arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < rows;i++){
arr.push(new Array(cols).fill(initialValue))
}
return arr;
}  

const board = generateBoard(3,3," ");

function indexToRowCol(board, i){
var row = parseInt(i/board[0].length);
var column = i - row*board[0].length - 1;

console.log(row);
console.log(column);
}

indexToRowCol(board, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function indexToRowCol(board, i){
  var row = parseInt(i/board[0].length);
  var col = i%board[0].length -1;
  return board[row][col];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually worked for me.

```
function indexToRowCol(board, i){
    var row = Math.floor((i/board.length));
    var col = (i - (row*(board.length)));

    return [row,col];
}
```

I was getting negative integers for some of the other responses but this seems to stop that.

Comment: you should put `- 1` for `col` or it will return the wrong value.